# How to Download Confluence site?

Tags: download, website, confluence

I have full read access to Cofluence, but cannot use Export functionality.

System Administrator do not want to give Administrative rights which are reuired to Export a space.

I want to read it when I'm out of office, e.g. on holidays at my country house.

I tried to use Offline Exporer Enterprise, but Confluence full of JavaScripts. OEE can't parse  all this menus.

Ofcourse I can download it manually... But it is a real hell, thousands of pages and files...

Comment: Have you tried something like HTTrack or wget/curl?

Comment: @Karan. Wget? Curl? There's one canonical HTTP page, everything else downloaded dynamically by JavaScript. Yes, we can track individual request, but it is useless outside of context. We don't like to read Ajax crap, we want read pages. There should be something that can translate dynamic pages to static pages, like static cache proxy, like in Opera Mini. Offline Explorer han handle this for simple pages, but not for Confluence :( Javascript in Confluence too heavy. We can try to use Firefox Scrapbook, but it will click on everything like "remove page" that is unacceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In OEE:

1. Disable parsing of JS
2. Limit downloading to main domain
3. Uncheck "level" checkbox, and OEE will try to download entire site.

Answer (score 0):

Browse -> Space Operations -> Export (PDF, HTML, XML) -> select pages you want

Comment: How does this answer the question? The OP explicitly stated that he/she does not have Administrative rights, which are required to Export a space.

Comment: I was able to export without admin rights. versions might affect here thou.